# How to do attachments in Yahoo groups

Tags: yahoo-groups

I'm a member of a private group on Yahoo, and when I (about once a month) submit a new "topic" and "attach" a document to it I get one of two different behaviors:

1. A link to the document shows up at the bottom of the body of the mailed post (mailed to everyone in the group), as a box at the top of the post as seen online, and as a separate entry on the group's "attachments" list.
2. The document appears at the bottom of the mailed post, in the fashion that's "normal" for a regular email, but does not appear at all in the online copy or in the "attachments" list.

I've seen both behaviors, and I don't know what I'm doing differently from one time to the next.

Can anyone tell me what causes one behavior vs the other?